# Insert all records from selected tables knowing records value

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Hi I wonder how I can insert to specyfic table, records from selected tables the same columns model. That's is a way to insert from only one table

```
insert  into  shema2.MAILING_PERSON_LOG_TAB
select  *  from  shema1.mailing_person_log_201008  t
where  t.object_type  =  'active'
```

and than I can select table names. Would somebody give me a hand, how do it from all tables using select or procedure

```
select t.TABLE_NAME FROM all_tables t WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'MAILING_PERSON_LOG%'
```

Comment: As you see yourself, it's a bad idea to add a table when adding data. This is not how databases are supposed to work. There should be only one table `mailing_person_log` with a column for the month (or date), so you'd only add rows to that table for new data. Then such problems how to write queries to select the data for more than one month simply wouldn't exist. My advice hence: Change your data model.

Answer (score 0):

Build the insert statement as a command string and execute it dynamically, e.g. (code for illustration, adapt it according to your requirements):

```
declare
  l_to_tablename varchar2(100);
begin
  -- loop over tables to copy
  for l_rec in (select t.TABLE_NAME
                  FROM all_tables t
                 WHERE t.table_name LIKE 'MAILING_PERSON_LOG%') loop

    -- determine to_tablename from somewhere
    select to_tablename
      into l_to_tablename
      from tablemapping t
     where t.table_name = l_rec.table_name;

    execute immediate 'insert  into  shema2.' || l_to_tablename ||
                      ' select  *  from  shema1.' || l_rec.table_name ||
                      ' t where  t.object_type  =  ''active''';

  end loop;
end;
```

note: this will not work if a table contains long-fields.

Comment: Developer getting error in line:
from tablemapping t

And I wonder where I should declare dest. table 
shema2.MAILING_PERSON_LOG_TAB

Comment: I have assumed you store the names of your source table and destination table in a table named `tablemapping`. As I alreade wrote above: Adjust this code for your needs.